# Setting the background color of FloatingActionButton with setBackgroundTintList

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am having an issue where by setting the background of a `FloatingActionButton` in the Design library, any other `FloatingActionButton` views which happen to be on the screen adopt the same color that was set on the original.

On the left is a screenshot of the application on a device running API 21. On the right, the device is running API 22 and the `FloatingActionButtons` all have the same color, despite their color being set differently for each.

[image: API 21] [image: API 22]

I have tested this in a blank application. Here is the XML for `activity_main`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_2"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_1"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab_2"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_3"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fab_2"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the relevant code for `MainActivity`. Other than this, no other code exists in the application.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Setting colors of first fab
    FloatingActionButton fab =
            (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_1);
    setFloatingActionButtonColors(fab,
            getResources().getColor(R.color.blue),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_dark));

    //Setting colors of second fab
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_2);
    setFloatingActionButtonColors(fab,
            getResources().getColor(R.color.red),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.red_dark));

    //Setting colors of third fab
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_3);
    setFloatingActionButtonColors(fab,
            getResources().getColor(R.color.green),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.green_dark));
}

private void setFloatingActionButtonColors(FloatingActionButton fab, int primaryColor, int rippleColor) {
    int[][] states = {
            {android.R.attr.state_enabled},
            {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
    };

    int[] colors = {
            primaryColor,
            rippleColor,
    };

    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
}
```

Finally, I have created a simple Android Studio project with the above code, which can be found [here](https://github.com/joseph-roque/fab-color-bug). There are some additional abnormalities in the project, if you want to test for yourself.

Has anybody encountered an issue like this before? Is this a known bug, or is there a workaround?

Comment: I had similar problem but with Setting fragments! - i I had set multi fragment in onCreate but return just one of fragment for all position of viewPager - at last one person said that set fragment in onResume not in one onCreate! - u can test this solution -i not sure but maybe contributory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks as though this is a bug with Android API 22. I have submitted a bug report to the Android issue tracker. The ticket can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181440).

Presently, I do not have a workaround, but will report back if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue was reported on google https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201873

But after release of Android Support Library, revision [23.2.1](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)  (March 2016) **This bug is solved.**

**FloatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(@Nullable ColorStateList tint) no longer changes background color**

update Support Library to `Android Support Library to 23.2.1`